# Oracle Extract returns null

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I have a question about the Oracle EXTRACT with XML data. I have this xml data:

```
<MSH xmlns="http://tempuri.org/layout.xsd">
    <PK_REPMSH>1</PK_REPMSH>
    <TIPO_OPER>A</TIPO_OPER>
    <TIPO_CHAVE>CHAVE</TIPO_CHAVE>
    <DATA_INC>20140508175904</DATA_INC>
    <HORA_INC>17:59</HORA_INC>
    <EVN>
        <TIPO_CHAVE_EVENTO>A1</TIPO_CHAVE_EVENTO>
        <DATA_INC_EVENTO>20140508175904</DATA_INC_EVENTO>
        <HORA_INC_EVENTO>17:59</HORA_INC_EVENTO>
    </EVN>
    <PID>
        <COD_PACIENTE>000001533</COD_PACIENTE>
        <PRIMEIRO_NOME>VINICIOS<PRIMEIRO_NOME>
        <ULTIMO_NOME>RODRIGUES</ULTIMO_NOME>
        <DATA_NASCIMENTO>151561321</DATA_NASCIMENTO>
        <SEXO>M</SEXO>
        <ENDERECO_RES>RUA DE MENTIRA</ENDERECO_RES>
        <NU_ENDERECO_RES>10</NU_ENDERECO_RES>
        <PAIS>BRASIL</PAIS>
        <CIDADE>RECIFE</CIDADE>
        <CEP>515160561</CEP>
        <DS_BAIRRO_RES>MENTIRINHA</DS_BAIRRO_RES>
    </PID>
</MSH>
```

I create this SQL to extract "PRIMEIRO_NOME" from XML data:

```
SELECT TRN_IN_ID, EXTRACT(xmlType(XML_BL_XML), '/MSH/PID/PRIMEIRO_NOME') AS XML_BL_XML FROM intp_lob_xml WHERE TRN_IN_ID = '1'
```

but the resultset of select is null XML_BL_XML.

```
TRN_IN_ID              XML_BL_XML                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
---------------------- ------------- 
1                      null
```

OBS: XML_BL_XML is a CLOB column.

How to solver this problem? Anybody can help me?

Comment: Try to check the result coming form that xmltype conversion function. You might have to add a second paramater to the function to set the character set id.

Comment: Oi @RenatoAfonso , a função xmlType retorna o xml normal. A parte de adicionar um segundo parâmetro eu não entendi muito bem, teria como mostrar um exemplo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> but the resultset of select is null

This is because there is a namespace specified in your xml document.

Here is an example using `extract()` function. Namespace is passed in as third parameter to the function:

```
with t1(xmldoc) as(
  select xmltype(
  '<MSH xmlns="http://tempuri.org/layout.xsd">
    <PK_REPMSH>1</PK_REPMSH>
    <TIPO_OPER>A</TIPO_OPER>
    <TIPO_CHAVE>CHAVE</TIPO_CHAVE>
    <DATA_INC>20140508175904</DATA_INC>
    <HORA_INC>17:59</HORA_INC>
    <EVN>
        <TIPO_CHAVE_EVENTO>A1</TIPO_CHAVE_EVENTO>
        <DATA_INC_EVENTO>20140508175904</DATA_INC_EVENTO>
        <HORA_INC_EVENTO>17:59</HORA_INC_EVENTO>
    </EVN>
    <PID>
        <COD_PACIENTE>000001533</COD_PACIENTE>
        <PRIMEIRO_NOME>VINICIOS</PRIMEIRO_NOME>
        <ULTIMO_NOME>RODRIGUES</ULTIMO_NOME>
        <DATA_NASCIMENTO>151561321</DATA_NASCIMENTO>
        <SEXO>M</SEXO>
        <ENDERECO_RES>RUA DE MENTIRA</ENDERECO_RES>
        <NU_ENDERECO_RES>10</NU_ENDERECO_RES>
        <PAIS>BRASIL</PAIS>
        <CIDADE>RECIFE</CIDADE>
        <CEP>515160561</CEP>
        <DS_BAIRRO_RES>MENTIRINHA</DS_BAIRRO_RES>
    </PID>
</MSH>') 
  from dual
)
select extract(xmldoc, 
              '/MSH/PID/PRIMEIRO_NOME/text()', 
              'xmlns="http://tempuri.org/layout.xsd"').getStringVal() as res
  from t1
```

Result:

```
RES               
----------------
VINICIOS        

1 row selected.
```

If there might be several PIDs and you need to return them all, `xmltable()` function can be used. Here we use `xmlnamespace` clause to specify a set of namespaces (first parameter of the `xmltable()` function).

```
   with t1(xmldoc) as(
      select xmltype(
      '<MSH xmlns="http://tempuri.org/layout.xsd">
        <PK_REPMSH>1</PK_REPMSH>
        <TIPO_OPER>A</TIPO_OPER>
        <TIPO_CHAVE>CHAVE</TIPO_CHAVE>
        <DATA_INC>20140508175904</DATA_INC>
        <HORA_INC>17:59</HORA_INC>
        <EVN>
            <TIPO_CHAVE_EVENTO>A1</TIPO_CHAVE_EVENTO>
            <DATA_INC_EVENTO>20140508175904</DATA_INC_EVENTO>
            <HORA_INC_EVENTO>17:59</HORA_INC_EVENTO>
        </EVN>
        <PID>
            <COD_PACIENTE>000001533</COD_PACIENTE>
            <PRIMEIRO_NOME>VINICIOS</PRIMEIRO_NOME>
            <ULTIMO_NOME>RODRIGUES</ULTIMO_NOME>
            <DATA_NASCIMENTO>151561321</DATA_NASCIMENTO>
            <SEXO>M</SEXO>
            <ENDERECO_RES>RUA DE MENTIRA</ENDERECO_RES>
            <NU_ENDERECO_RES>10</NU_ENDERECO_RES>
            <PAIS>BRASIL</PAIS>
            <CIDADE>RECIFE</CIDADE>
            <CEP>515160561</CEP>
            <DS_BAIRRO_RES>MENTIRINHA</DS_BAIRRO_RES>
        </PID>
        <PID> <PRIMEIRO_NOME>VINICIOS 2</PRIMEIRO_NOME> </PID>
    </MSH>') 
      from dual
    )
 select prim
  from t1
  cross join xmltable(xmlnamespaces(default 'http://tempuri.org/layout.xsd'),
                      '/MSH/PID' passing t1.xmldoc
                      columns prim varchar2(255) path 'PRIMEIRO_NOME')
```

Result:

```
PRIM                  
-----------------
VINICIOS                     
VINICIOS 2                   

2 rows selected.
```